# Opentok video call ge the speaker subscriber Id

Tags: angular6, opentok

I ahve integrated the OT video call session in my angular 6.

This is the publisher stream  code

```
    const publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher', {
     name: 'pubname',
  style: { 'buttonDisplayMode': 'off'},
  insertMode: 'append',
  width: '100%',
  fitMode: 'contain',
  height: '100%'
  });
```

This is the subscribers streaam code:

```
session.subscribe(event.stream, dup_div, {
  insertMode: 'append',
  name:'subname',
 style: { 'buttonDisplayMode': 'off'},
width: '100%',
fitMode: 'contain',
height: '100%'
});
```

THis is working fine. I have 4 subscribers in my stream. If so I wan to get Who is speaking. That is, If subscriber 1 asking question, Then Others should get Subscriber1 is speaking. So I want to get the subscriber's id who is speaking. 
How can I get this using `captureStream()` or `getAudioTracks()`.

Please help me to find this. I didn't get any examples or sample code regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options here I can think of.

1. You can use the [Subscriber "audioLevelUpdated" Events](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#events) and if they are over a threshold then you say that the user is speaking. Something like:

   ```
   const subscriber = session.subscribe(stream);
   subscriber.on('audioLevelUpdated', () => {
     if (movingAvg === null || movingAvg <= event.audioLevel) {
       movingAvg = event.audioLevel;
     } else {
       movingAvg = 0.7 * movingAvg + 0.3 * event.audioLevel;
     }

     // 1.5 scaling to map the -30 - 0 dBm range to [0,1]
     let logLevel = (Math.log(movingAvg) / Math.LN10) / 1.5 + 1;
     logLevel = Math.min(Math.max(logLevel, 0), 1);
     if (logLevel > 0.5) {
       // They are speaking, do whatever you need to do here
     }
   });
   ```
2. You could use the [hark.js library](https://github.com/otalk/hark) which already has useful 'speaking' events and then send those events to the other participants.

   ```
   const publisher = OT.initPublisher();
   // Create a new MediaStream with the audio track from the Publisher
   const mediaStream = new MediaStream([publisher.getAudioSource()]);
   const speech = hark(mediaStream, options);
   speech.on('speaking', () => {
     // They are speaking
     session.signal({ type: 'speaking'});
   });
   const subscribersByConnectionId = {};
   session.on('streamCreated', (event) => {
     const subscriber = session.subscribe(event.stream);
     subscribersByConnectionId[event.stream.connection.connectionId] = subscriber;
     subscriber.on('destroyed', (event) => {
       delete subscribersByConnectionId[event.stream.connection.connectionId];
     });
   });
   session.on('signal:speaking', (event) => {
     const subscriberSpeaking = subscribersByConnectionId[event.from.connectionId];
     // Do whatever you want with the subscriber that is speaking
   });
   ```